# JCache infinispan entry listeners not firing

Tags: java, wildfly-10, infinispan

I am working with a maven project with this configuration:

- java 8
- Wildfly 10.1.0.Final
- Maven infinispan-jcache:

  ```
       <dependency>
         <groupId>org.infinispan</groupId>
         <artifactId>infinispan-jcache</artifactId>
         <version>7.1.0.Final</version>
       </dependency>
  ```

Then I define a method with @CacheResult annotation this way:

```
 @CacheResult(cacheName = "customCacheName")
 public Double getCustomAttribute(String id){
 [...]
 }
```

I want to do something when an object is added to the cache, so I started working with CacheEntryEventListener. I developed my custom listener this way:

```
public class MyCustomCacheEntryEventListener implements CacheEntryCreatedListener<Object, Object>, Serializable
{
    public MyCustomCacheEntryEventListener()
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreated(Iterable<CacheEntryEvent< ? extends Object, ? extends Object>> events)
        throws CacheEntryListenerException
    {
        LOG.info("onCreated invoked");

        for (CacheEntryEvent< ? extends Object, ? extends Object> event : events) {
            LOG.info("Received a " + event);
        }
    }
}
```

To finish configuration I have this code called in a @Startup bean:

```
CachingProvider provider = Caching.getCachingProvider();
CacheManager manager = provider.getCacheManager();

CacheEntryListenerConfiguration<Object, Object> listenerConfiguration =
            new MutableCacheEntryListenerConfiguration<>(FactoryBuilder.factoryOf(new MyCustomCacheEntryEventListener()),
                null, false, true);

CompleteConfiguration<Object, Object> config = new MutableConfiguration<>().setTypes(Object.class, Object.class).addCacheEntryListenerConfiguration(listenerConfiguration);

manager.createCache("customCacheName", config).registerCacheEntryListener(listenerConfiguration);
```

JCache annotations are working fine. I also added **TRACE** logging to org.infinispan to have more information.

Entry event listeners are not fired.

Any help is appreciated.
Regards,
Juan

Comment: Can you try with latest Infinispan 9.2.0.CR2 release? We have added JCache 1.1 support there and wondering if the same issue still persists.

Comment: I tried with 9.2.0.CR2 release and issue still persists. Entry event listeners are not fired. If I do the following: `org.infinispan.Cache unwrap = (org.infinispan.Cache) jcache.unwrap(org.infinispan.Cache.class); unwrap.getCacheManager().addListener(new CustomListener());`, then cache @CacheStarted method from _CustomListener_ class is fired. But registering the infinispan listener `unwrap.addListener(new CustomCacheEntryListener());` where **CustomCacheEntryListener** class is a @Listener (org.infinispan.notifications.Listener) is never fired.

Comment: I did some more tests. Created another cache named "customCacheName2" which is not used with the annotation @CacheResult. Then if I register the above listener with this cache and put an element programmatically, I see the _cache entry created event gets fired_ ... Is it possible that the annotation CacheResult could create the cache "customCacheName" with default configuration before my Startup bean attemps to create it?

Comment: @GalderZamarreño digging more into the problem, I found that if a method with CacheResult(name="customCacheName") is invoked and "customCacheName" cache is missing, then default configuration is used to create it. So, following the server log events I see that then appears my programmatic cache creation in Startup bean and log says: **Cache already registered**. Do you think this could be the cause of the new configuration being omitted and listener not created? I saw also an interesting link: http://blog.tremblay.pro/2017/02/jcache.html. Do you think it is possible to take a similar approach?

Comment: Hmmm, dunno. Have you tried to predefine the cache in the server's configuration and see if that works? If you do that, you might have to change the call to `createCache` to be `getCache`.

Comment: You mean defining the cache in a configuration file instead of programmatically in code?

Comment: Yup, in the Wildfly configuration file.

Comment: I had a similar issue and solved it by calling `cache.addListener(eventListener)` instead of `cacheManager.addListener(eventListener)`